# use same NSURLConnection to call different webservice method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, web-services, nsurlconnection, nsurl

scenario :
on 1st view i am sending a SOAP message with NSURLConnection to call webservie(method 1)
now when i am going to 3rd view, here i want to call webservice(method 2) should i have to use NSURLConnection again ?
And also at 1st time of connection i am checking for "https" "username" and "password" so should i have to do this again for 3rd view also...?
i mean, whenever i want to call webservice(method N) i have to do NSURLConnection and verification and validation things .
can we use same connection for all calling ?and only one time verification?

thank you in advance